# Multiple Condition in XSLT not working

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<bp_list xmlns="http://example.com/2012/03/01/canonical/BusinessPartner">
<total_count>221</total_count>
<bp>
    <bp_id>10</bp_id>
    <bp_name>aad</bp_name>
    <last_changed_date>2016-12-20T02:38:14</last_changed_date>
    <location>
        <location_id>200020</location_id>
        <location_name>gfh</location_name>
        <is_location_owner>true</is_location_owner>
        <location_registration_status>
            <registration_status_id>7202</registration_status_id>
            <registration_status_name>Unregistered</registration_status_name>
            <registration_status_effective_date>2015-07-24T00:00:00</registration_status_effective_date>
        </location_registration_status>
        <location_status>
            <name>In Progress</name>
        </location_status>
        <marked_for_delete>false</marked_for_delete>
        <bp_location>
            <bp>
                <bp_id>10</bp_id>
            </bp>
            <bp_location_capability>
                <is_primary_capability>true</is_primary_capability>
                <location_function_capability_category_id>50</location_function_capability_category_id>
                <location_function_capability_name>hq</location_function_capability_name>
            </bp_location_capability>
            <bp_location_capability>
                <is_primary_capability>true</is_primary_capability>
                <location_function_capability_category_id>53</location_function_capability_category_id>
                <location_function_capability_name>Remit To</location_function_capability_name>
            </bp_location_capability>
        </bp_location>
        <address>
            <id>103754</id>
            <line1>someadress</line1>
            <city>Columbus</city>
            <postal_code>47201</postal_code>
            <country_code>US</country_code>
            <country_name>UNITED STATES</country_name>
            <subdivision_code>US-IN     </subdivision_code>
            <subdivision_name>Indiana</subdivision_name>
            <validation_status>0</validation_status>
        </address>
        <location_type>
            <location_type_id>5003</location_type_id>
            <location_type_name>Business Office</location_type_name>
        </location_type>
        <location_type>
            <location_type_id>5002</location_type_id>
            <location_type_name>Warehouse</location_type_name>
        </location_type>
        <location_capability>
            <location_capability_id>13</location_capability_id>
            <location_capability_name>Stores Cartons</location_capability_name>
            <location_capability_category>1</location_capability_category>
        </location_capability>
        <location_capability>
            <location_capability_id>50</location_capability_id>
            <location_capability_name>hq</location_capability_name>
            <location_capability_category>2</location_capability_category>
        </location_capability>
        <location_capability>
            <location_capability_id>53</location_capability_id>
            <location_capability_name>Remit To</location_capability_name>
            <location_capability_category>2</location_capability_category>
        </location_capability>
    </location>
    <location>
        <location_id>16677059</location_id>
        <location_name>ggg(something Co. Ltd)</location_name>
        <is_location_owner>false</is_location_owner>
        <location_registration_status>
            <registration_status_id>7202</registration_status_id>
            <registration_status_name>Unregistered</registration_status_name>
        </location_registration_status>
        <location_status>
            <name>In Progress</name>
        </location_status>
        <marked_for_delete>false</marked_for_delete>
        <bp_location>
            <bp>
                <bp_id>29303</bp_id>
            </bp>
        </bp_location>
        <address>
            <id>122088</id>
            <line1>No.139 abc.</line1>
            <line2>down the woods</line2>
            <city>ff</city>
            <postal_code>4567</postal_code>
            <country_code>CN</country_code>
            <country_name>CHINA</country_name>
            <subdivision_code>r5     </subdivision_code>
            <subdivision_name>Fujian</subdivision_name>
            <validation_status>1702</validation_status>
        </address>
        <location_type>
            <location_type_id>5001</location_type_id>
            <location_type_name>Factory</location_type_name>
        </location_type>
        <location_capability>
            <location_capability_id>10</location_capability_id>
            <location_capability_name>Produces Product</location_capability_name>
            <location_capability_category>1</location_capability_category>
        </location_capability>
    </location>
    </bp>
```

I have to take the Line1 and Line 2 of the address where "Is Primary capability" is true and "Location function capability" is hq.

In this particular situation, I should not get anything in line2 because the address does not have any (For the above address that fulfills the condition). However my XSLT is picking up the line2 from the next address. This has me believing that the condition that I have coded is not working.Although I am getting the expected output in Line1, it is only because it it is the very first address. Below is my XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:ns="http://target.com/2012/03/01/canonical/BusinessPartner">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">bp_name|bp_id|line1|line2
    <xsl:for-each select="ns:bp_list/ns:bp">
        <xsl:variable name="bp_name" select="normalize-space(ns:bp_name)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$bp_name"/>|<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(ns:bp_id)"/>|<xsl:if test="((ns:location/ns:bp_location/ns:bp_location_capability/ns:is_primary_capability = 'true') and (ns:location/ns:bp_location/ns:bp_location_capability/ns:location_function_capability_name = 'hq'))"> <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(ns:location/ns:address/ns:line1)"/></xsl:if>|<xsl:if test="((ns:location/ns:bp_location/ns:bp_location_capability/ns:is_primary_capability = 'true') and (ns:location/ns:bp_location/ns:bp_location_capability/ns:location_function_capability_name = 'hq'))"> <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(ns:location/ns:address/ns:line2)"/><xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each></xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

What can be the issue here and how can I resolve this?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: Yes Daniel, Thank you. You were right in your assessment and I was able to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're checking to see if a location meets your conditions, but you don't target that location specifically.

You can move your conditions into a predicate on `location` and output the address only for that location.

Example...

**XML Input**

```
<bp_list xmlns="http://example.com/2012/03/01/canonical/BusinessPartner">
    <total_count>221</total_count>
    <bp>
        <bp_id>10</bp_id>
        <bp_name>aad</bp_name>
        <last_changed_date>2016-12-20T02:38:14</last_changed_date>
        <location>
            <location_id>200020</location_id>
            <location_name>gfh</location_name>
            <is_location_owner>true</is_location_owner>
            <location_registration_status>
                <registration_status_id>7202</registration_status_id>
                <registration_status_name>Unregistered</registration_status_name>
                <registration_status_effective_date>2015-07-24T00:00:00</registration_status_effective_date>
            </location_registration_status>
            <location_status>
                <name>In Progress</name>
            </location_status>
            <marked_for_delete>false</marked_for_delete>
            <bp_location>
                <bp>
                    <bp_id>10</bp_id>
                </bp>
                <bp_location_capability>
                    <is_primary_capability>true</is_primary_capability>
                    <location_function_capability_category_id>50</location_function_capability_category_id>
                    <location_function_capability_name>hq</location_function_capability_name>
                </bp_location_capability>
                <bp_location_capability>
                    <is_primary_capability>true</is_primary_capability>
                    <location_function_capability_category_id>53</location_function_capability_category_id>
                    <location_function_capability_name>Remit To</location_function_capability_name>
                </bp_location_capability>
            </bp_location>
            <address>
            <id>103754</id>
            <line1>someadress</line1>
            <city>Columbus</city>
            <postal_code>47201</postal_code>
            <country_code>US</country_code>
            <country_name>UNITED STATES</country_name>
            <subdivision_code>US-IN     </subdivision_code>
            <subdivision_name>Indiana</subdivision_name>
            <validation_status>0</validation_status>
        </address>
            <location_type>
                <location_type_id>5003</location_type_id>
                <location_type_name>Business Office</location_type_name>
            </location_type>
            <location_type>
                <location_type_id>5002</location_type_id>
                <location_type_name>Warehouse</location_type_name>
            </location_type>
            <location_capability>
                <location_capability_id>13</location_capability_id>
                <location_capability_name>Stores Cartons</location_capability_name>
                <location_capability_category>1</location_capability_category>
            </location_capability>
            <location_capability>
                <location_capability_id>50</location_capability_id>
                <location_capability_name>hq</location_capability_name>
                <location_capability_category>2</location_capability_category>
            </location_capability>
            <location_capability>
                <location_capability_id>53</location_capability_id>
                <location_capability_name>Remit To</location_capability_name>
                <location_capability_category>2</location_capability_category>
            </location_capability>
        </location>
        <location>
            <location_id>16677059</location_id>
            <location_name>ggg(something Co. Ltd)</location_name>
            <is_location_owner>false</is_location_owner>
            <location_registration_status>
                <registration_status_id>7202</registration_status_id>
                <registration_status_name>Unregistered</registration_status_name>
            </location_registration_status>
            <location_status>
                <name>In Progress</name>
            </location_status>
            <marked_for_delete>false</marked_for_delete>
            <bp_location>
                <bp>
                    <bp_id>29303</bp_id>
                </bp>
            </bp_location>
            <address>
            <id>122088</id>
            <line1>No.139 abc.</line1>
            <line2>down the woods</line2>
            <city>ff</city>
            <postal_code>4567</postal_code>
            <country_code>CN</country_code>
            <country_name>CHINA</country_name>
            <subdivision_code>r5     </subdivision_code>
            <subdivision_name>Fujian</subdivision_name>
            <validation_status>1702</validation_status>
        </address>
            <location_type>
                <location_type_id>5001</location_type_id>
                <location_type_name>Factory</location_type_name>
            </location_type>
            <location_capability>
                <location_capability_id>10</location_capability_id>
                <location_capability_name>Produces Product</location_capability_name>
                <location_capability_category>1</location_capability_category>
            </location_capability>
        </location>
    </bp>
</bp_list>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ns="http://example.com/2012/03/01/canonical/BusinessPartner">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>bp_name|bp_id|line1|line2&#xA;</xsl:text> 
    <xsl:for-each select="ns:bp_list/ns:bp/ns:location[
      ns:bp_location/ns:bp_location_capability[
      ns:is_primary_capability = 'true' and ns:location_function_capability_name = 'hq']]">
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(../ns:bp_name)"/>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(../ns:bp_id)"/>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(ns:address/ns:line1)"/>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(ns:address/ns:line2)"/>
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
bp_name|bp_id|line1|line2
aad|10|someadress|
```